# how to store value in array & then it use in other?

Tags: php

i am performing search condition of image file & using `print_r()` it shows output of image path in array. now i want to store this array & perform search operation for particular image path in that stored array.
this is code of searching image file:

> $root1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
>
> $directory = $root1.'/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/';
>
> $it = new
>   RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));
>   $i=0;
>   $num=1;
>   while($it->valid() and $iisDot()) {
>           $files = glob($directory.$it->getSubPath().'/*.jpg');
>           print_r($files);
>
> $i++;
>       }
>     $it->next(); }

& output is:

> Array ( [0] => C:/Program
>   Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports19.jpg
>   [1] => C:/Program
>   Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports21.jpg
>   [2] => C:/Program
>   Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg
>   [3] => C:/Program
>   Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports3.jpg
>   )

now i want store this output in a variable or in array.
after that i want to perform search action on that variable or array, like find the path of `"C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-5.3.2i/www/Place4Info/Data/Admin_data/admin/sports22.jpg "` file. & store that result in variable. 
i got one code but i dont know how to apply this.

> $conditions = array("Post.title<>" =>
>   $files);
>           $this->Post->find('sports3.jpg',
>   array('conditions' => $conditions));
>         echo $this;

but it give error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\Temp\test.php on line 17
```

Comment: Your question is not about how to use arrays but how to avoid a logic error in your programming.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the basics of PHP programming, my friend.  Your question is not about how to use arrays but how to avoid a logic error in your programming.  See my answer.

$this is a magic variable that always represents the actual instance pointer of a substantiated class.  E.g. it makes **no** sense to use it outside of a non-static class context, which is what you're doing.

Figure out which class has the correct Post object and use its API appropriately.

e.g.

```
$post = new Post;
$post->find('sports3.jpg', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Comment: My pleasure!  There should be a badge called "First person to thank you" lol.